# Plotting circle markers with radius with leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I have a dataset zipdata which looks like this:

```
 $ zipcode  : int  123 124 125 126
 $ latitude : num  28.4 18.6 12.6 22.3
 $ longitude: num  77.1 74.3 77.3 88.2
 $ adultpop : int  15000 12000 9000 16000
 $ income   : int  5000 2000 9500 1000
```

If this is valid:

```
leaflet(data = zipdata) %>%
  clearShapes() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircles(~longitude, ~latitude, radius = (zipdata$income/max(zipdata$income))*300000,
             layerId = ~zipcode, stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.4)
```

Why is this not valid? If I run this, it does not give me the radius as I want:

```
leaflet(data = zipdata) %>%
   clearShapes() %>%
   addTiles() %>%
   addCircles(~longitude, ~latitude, radius = (zipdata[,5]/max(zipdata[,5]))*300000,
              layerId = ~zipcode, stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.4)
```

Comment: Could you share your `zipdata` ? It would be easier to help you.